# How can I call and run a function with given number of inputs using mouseDoubleClickEvent of a GraphicsView which is in a QMainWindow?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

How can I call and run a function with given number of inputs using mouseDoubleClickEvent of a GraphicsView which is in a QMainWindow?

## My schematic code:

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    ...

    def __setUI(self, appTitle="[default title]"):
        ...

        self.graphicsView = GraphicsView(self)

        self.graphicsView.mouseDoubleClickEvent = self.MyFunc(self.in_1, self.in_2)

     def MyFunc(self, event, input_1, input_2):
        ...
```

I used this code, but is doesn't work. please help me to know how I can call 
 and run MyFunc using mouseDoubleClickEvent of graphicsView which is in MainWindow.

Many Thanks

Comment: `GraphicsView` is an `QGraphicsView`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to pass a lambda, something like:

```
self.graphicsView.mouseDoubleClickEvent = lambda event : self.MyFunc(self.in_1, self.in_2)
```

It works but it generates problems since mouseDoubleClickEvent has implementation that with the previous code is deleted. In this case the best solution is to use an eventFilter but to viewport since it receives the mouse event.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.graphicsView = QtWidgets.QGraphicsView()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.graphicsView)
        self.graphicsView.viewport().installEventFilter(self)

        self.in_1 = 10
        self.in_2 = 20

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if obj is self.graphicsView.viewport():
            if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.MouseButtonDblClick:
                self.func(event)
        return super(MainWindow, self).eventFilter(obj, event)

    def func(self, event):
        print(event.pos(), self.in_1, self.in_2)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Dear Eyllanesc, thanks for your help. The function that I use should accept two any optional inputs. In the code that you have written above, the func function does not have any inputs. In this case I can solve the problem in other simplest ways, but my main problem is with the inputs.

Comment: @Mohsen How do you get the other 2 inputs ?, in the general case what is done is that those 2 inputs are members of the class as I have proposed in my solution.

Comment: I solved the problem by a little change in your above-mentioned help (the 1st line about lambda) as follows:

self.graphicsView.mouseDoubleClickEvent = lambda event : self.MyFunc(event, self.in_1, self.in_2)

* I added "event" within the function.

Thanks

Comment: @Mohsen If my answer helps you do not forget to mark it as correct